# Reuse data from api when i get back same route, angular 6

Tags: angular, api, angular2-routing, angular6

my home route has 2-3 API, which fetches some data from service through httpClient. when I leave this route and came back again these API calls again. I don't want to request the same data again? Is there a way to store these responses and get those from there without requesting server?

Comment: Why not store the data in a service property and then check if the data is already there. If it's there, don't make the API call again. If it's not, go ahead and make the API call again.

Comment: @SiddAjmera ok that seems a great idea. but I have a question when we call an API from service we need to subscribe that response from component right? so, how do I save the response in service?

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to do this is by caching the api request's responses. you can do this in multiple ways

1. by manually storing them in LocalStorage
2. using a third party library example https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-async-cache

I also found some good articles about the same hope they help you

1. https://itnext.io/improve-your-angular-app-performance-by-using-this-simple-observable-cache-decorator-71e81dfa76ae
2. https://fullstack-developer.academy/caching-http-requests-with-angular/